# Attempting to write a query but not sure what to do

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query where For each member, list member id and the number of books ever checked out by that member.  I was trying to do it like this (which i know is wrong):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, COUNT(DateChkOut)
FROM MEMBER, CHECK_OUT
WHERE MEMBER.ID = CHECK_OUT.MemID;
```

I am not sure how to go about creating query.  If somebody can please give me some tips/hints it would be appreciated.  Thank you.  Below are my tables needed for this query.

```
SQL> select * from MEMBER;

    ID MEMNAME
---------- ---------------
    12 Randy Kaplan
     4 Linda Day
     9 Joo Tan

SQL> SELECT * FROM CHECK_OUT;

DATECHKOU CAT#                 MEMID DATEDUE   DATERET
--------- --------------- ---------- --------- ---------
15-MAR-11 T 430.98 195             4 14-JUN-11 31-MAY-11
15-MAR-11 B 125.2 2013            12 14-JUN-11
27-DEC-12 T 430.98 195             4 25-MAR-13
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or ORACLE? Also, format  your dates correctly and consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
FROM MEMBER
JOIN CHECK_OUT
ON MEMBER.ID = CHECK_OUT.MemID
GROUP BY ID;
```

This won't show members who have never checked out anything. For that, you need an outer join:

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(COUNT(DateChkOut), 0) AS Count
FROM MEMBER
LEFT JOIN CHECK_OUT
ON MEMBER.ID = CHECK_OUT.MemID
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  I haven't done DB in a while.  I forgot about the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't that far away, as far as I can tell you just needed to add a `GROUP BY` clause, which groups by `ID` and gets a count of the books per `ID`. Something like this:

```
SELECT MEMBER.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM MEMBER, CHECK_OUT
WHERE MEMBER.ID = CHECK_OUT.MemID
GROUP BY MEMBER.ID;
```